# spark-ec2 not recognized when lauching cluster on windows 8.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, spark-ec2

I'm a complete beginner on spark. I'm trying to run spark on Amazon EC2, but my system does not recognize "spark-ec2" or "./spark-ec2". It says "spark-ec2" is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I followed the instruction [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html) to launch a cluster. I would like to use Scala, how do I make it work?

Comment: It doesn't look like the script is designed to run on windows. Although you can probably run the python script directly. But the problem you are having is likely due to not being in the correct directory within command line.

Comment: Do you mean in the ec2 folder? I did actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add PYTHON PATH environment variable with boto.
PYTHONPATH="${SPARK_EC2_DIR}/third_party/boto-2.4.1.zip/boto-2.4.1:$PYTHONPATH"
And execute the python script

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would this work if I need to use Scala?

Comment: I am not sure if you can start a spark-ec2 cluster with scala. I always use the spark-ec2 script to launch a cluster.

Comment: PATHONPATH is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: add these lines to the top of the spark-ec2.py python script.                                        `import sys                                              sys.path.append("/your/spark/directory/thirdparty/boto-2.4.1.zip/boto-2.4.1")`

Answer (score 1):

In order to run the Spark-EC2 script on Windows you need Cygwin and Python. If you don't want to install these programs, you can use the dockerized version of the script (https://github.com/edrevo/spark-ec2-docker), which only depends on Docker.